# What is the common way to say "the rain reduced in intensity"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

If I had to say - "as soon as ***the rain reduced in intensity***" , what word should I use in casual everyday speech? I'm not looking for another word like subsided etc. I need to know the commonly used word here.

Comment: *The rain let up.*

Comment: "The rain eased off" is common in BrE, but not AmE according to ngram.

Comment: In Britain, where we are experts in everything concerning what the weather is doing, it is *eased off*. If the rain was especially hard, we sometimes say *there was no let up*. But *let up* seems to me less common in the affirmative.

Comment: Another common U.S. idiomatic wording is "[the rain tapered off](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rain+tapered+off&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crain%20tapered%20off%3B%2Cc0)."

Comment: @WS2 aren't you just experts in everything rain is doing? ;)

Comment: @Helmar We sometimes say  *The sun's trying to get out*. But the point is that the only thing that is certain about our climate is its unpredictability. And because of that the weather is always being talked about.

Comment: @WS2 - "The rain let up" would be quite idiomatic in the US.  As in "That afternoon the rain finally let up enough for us to visit the shrine."

Comment: In context, it is often enough to use just "it let up".

Comment: @HotLicks Very odd it is, when you think about it. It doesn't sound idiomatic to me exactly like that. But it would be perfectly normal to say something like "It was bucketing down all afternoon - there was no let up". I think we only use *let up* in the negative i.e. It *didn't* let up. But then it rains differently in America. Friends who have lived in Washington DC tell me there is no such thing as a *shower* i.e. a short burst of rain lasting about 10 - 15 minutes - after which the sun comes out again. *Showers* are characteristic of many summer days at the English seaside!

Comment: @WS2 - "Bucketing down" is not something that one would hear in the US, at least not in this part of the country.  "Showers", on the other hand, are quite common, and is the terminology often used by weather forecasters.

Comment: @HotLicks *Bucketing down, tipping it down, or chucking it down* are all metaphors for heavy rain. But would people shelter under a tree in the knowledge that "it is only a shower" and will be over in a few minutes?

Comment: @WS2 - That would depend on local weather patterns (and the degree of optimism of the people).  There are times here when a "shower" will blow through for a few minutes and then the sun will pop out again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many idiomatic options:

- the rain **eased off**
- the rain **let up**
- the rain **slackened off**
- the rain **eased up**
- the rain **tapered off**

[Google ngram showing relative usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20rain%20eased%20off%2C%20the%20rain%20let%20up%2C%20the%20rain%20slackened%20off%2C%20the%20rain%20eased%20up%2C%20the%20rain%20tapered%20off&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20rain%20eased%20off%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20rain%20let%20up%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20rain%20slackened%20off%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20rain%20eased%20up%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20rain%20tapered%20off%3B%2Cc0)

You can even replace "the rain" with "it", as long as its already clear from context that it's raining. Random examples:

> As if to prove that the weather was definitely not on his side today, the rain grew heavier.
>
> "The band stand's just around the corner. We could shelter there till **it eases off**. The weather report said 'A few showers'."
>
> *[The Wishing Well](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=8hWWCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT90&dq=%22it%20eases%20off%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwintcXmsfDOAhUBOpoKHWN4CUsQ6AEITTAI#v=onepage&q=%22it%20eases%20off%22&f=false) by Anna Jacobs*

and

> "Sarge, got the base on the radio. They said that they expect a break in the weather at anytime. They'll have a chopper inbound as soon as **it lets up**."
>
> *[Return To Hell: U.S. Marines In (Vietnam)](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=0dPbOyZbnUoC&pg=PA242&dq=%22it%20lets%20up%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjH2OzSsvDOAhUBJpoKHXG_D2EQ6AEINDAE#v=onepage&q=%22it%20lets%20up%22&f=false) by Charles F. David*